# Can a changelog topic be reused?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I intend to share data aggregated by one stream with another one to reduce (re)processing time when restarting services or rebuilding aggregates.
This stream creates a store which the changelog topic belongs to:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun wirtschaftseinheiten() = Consumer<KStream<String, WirtschaftseinheitAggregat>> {
        it.toTable(Materialized.`as`(wirtschaftseinheitTableStoreSupplier))
    }
```

And this is how I join the changelog topic:

```kotlin
fun KStream<String, ProjektEvent>.leftJoin(wirtschaftseinheiten: KTable<String, WirtschaftseinheitAggregat>): KTable<String, ProjektAggregat> =
        mapValues { _, v -> ProjektAggregat(projekt = v, projektErstelltAm = v.metaInfo.createdAt) }
            .groupByKey()
            // take the earliest date which should be from event with ACTION = CREATE_REQUEST
            .reduce { prev, next -> if (next.projektErstelltAm?.isAfter(prev.projektErstelltAm) == true) next.copy(projektErstelltAm = prev.projektErstelltAm) else next }
            .toStream()
            .toTable(Materialized.`as`(preliminaryProjektStoreSupplier))
            .leftJoin(
                wirtschaftseinheiten,
                { projektAggregat -> projektAggregat.projekt?.projekt?.technischerPlatz?.take(7) },
                { projektAggregat, wirtschaftseinheit ->
                    if (wirtschaftseinheit != null) {
                        projektAggregat + wirtschaftseinheit
                    } else {
                        logger().error("No wirtschaftseinheit found for $projektAggregat")
                        projektAggregat
                    }
                },
                Materialized.`as`(projektWirtschaftseinheitJoinStoreSupplier)
            )
```

but unfortunately no match will be found as the right side is always null.

If I directly join the topic, then it of course works, but du to migrations I have to rebuild topics which also means consuming the topic declared in wirtschaftseinheitTableStoreSupplier and this is time-consuming.

So therefore a general question: is this a feasible way? If not, is there a better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from KTable to GlobalKTable solved the issue

```kotlin
fun KStream<String, ProjektEvent>.leftJoin(wirtschaftseinheiten: GlobalKTable<String, WirtschaftseinheitAggregat>): KTable<String, ProjektAggregat> =
        mapValues { _, v -> ProjektAggregat(projekt = v, projektErstelltAm = v.metaInfo.createdAt) }
            .groupByKey()
            // take the earliest date which should be from event with ACTION = CREATE_REQUEST
            .reduce(
                { current, next ->
                    if (next.projektErstelltAm?.isAfter(current.projektErstelltAm) == true)
                        next.copy(projektErstelltAm = current.projektErstelltAm)
                    else
                        next
                },
                Materialized.`as`(preliminaryProjektStoreSupplier)
            )
            .toStream()
            .leftJoin(
                wirtschaftseinheiten,
                { _, projektAggregat -> projektAggregat.projekt?.projekt?.technischerPlatz?.take(7) },
                { projektAggregat, wirtschaftseinheit ->
                    if (wirtschaftseinheit != null) {
                        projektAggregat + wirtschaftseinheit
                    } else {
                        logger().error("No wirtschaftseinheit found for $projektAggregat")
                        projektAggregat
                    }
                },
            )
            .toTable(Materialized.`as`(projektWirtschaftseinheitJoinStoreSupplier))
```